# jquery tab error problem

Tags: jquery, tabs

Hello all im trying jquery and im trying to make a simple tab menu, but i just cant get it to hide my content, you can see what i have made here

http://jsfiddle.net/YyJ7V/

hope you can tell me what im doing wrong

Comment: It's quite important, when putting together a jQuery demo, to **use** jQuery (as opposed to, for example, **MooTools**). Remember to check the drop-down on the left... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
$(function() {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide();
    $('.tabsNavigation a').click(
        function(){
            var which = $(this).parent().index();
            $(tabContainers).eq(which).show().siblings().filter('div').hide();
            return false;
        });
})
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/37KWs/).

Notes:

- As implied in my comment to your question: you were using MooTools, rather than jQuery in your demo. This won't work. Or it might, but probably rarely, due to syntax/use-differences
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) was misspelled, and so couldn't work.
- I I couldn't see, in your demo, any click-handling to effect an action, so I added that in.

Comment: Thanks so much, but @david i will try to make it on my own so i own what the code do so i can learn :), i have now this but it dont change the content when i click on a link, can you see whats wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/YyJ7V/9/

Comment: okay tabsNavigation was misspelled, (its late in denmark) haha :D thanks so much again i think i can work it out from here ;)

Comment: @david do you know if i can change the id="tab1" etc. to class ?

Comment: @Sjmon: no problem at all! Best of luck with the rest of it. And yes, you can. Though I'm not sure what the context of your question is, or *why* you're asking. But I Can't think of a reason you **shouldn't** / **couldn't** use a class.

Comment: @David Thomas but the thing is, if i change it to class'es it dont show the content of the tabs when i click on them :S

Comment: @Sjmon, could you post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo for me, and I'll have a look for you?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/YyJ7V/3/

```
$(function() {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabContainers.hide().filter('#tab1').show();
})
```

Filter was mispelled, also changed to # instead of :, and it seems to work. Also like David Thomas posted above I had to change it to jquery in js fiddle, it was set to mootools by default.